# What benchmarks/baselines do you know in the topic of forecasting non-linear chaotic systems?

Tags: neural-networks, nonlinear-regression, nonlinearity

I would like to know what established benchmarks/baselines are in use to predict (forecast) chaotic series when we treat those as time-series problems:

- "Datasets" (=equations) (e.g. logistic map, Lorenz attractor equations)
- Evaluation methods (MAE, MSE)
- Models to compare myself to

As I saw in the machine learning and deep learning world, the publications do not compare their models to other methods so, it is really hard to see improvements overt time. Maybe I am missing something, and this is what I would like to learn about.

Comment: Interesting question. Are you assuming that your data has a "ground truth" which can serve as a fixed point of reference? In the absence of one, performance is self-benchmarking, based on out-of-sample data and metrics. Otherwise, I've always like Mandelbrot's approach to chaotic systems, his metric Mandelbrot's *D* and related papers might be helpful. Mandelbrot also championed the Hurst exponent, *h*, for time series and discussed classification into types of randomness based on the value of *h*. See his papers on hydrology referencing the Noah and Joseph effects.

Comment: What I am thinking about is that I have a "Ground Truth" dataset (as you described) where I make a train-test split. I create a model with the train set and then I measure the performance on the test set. I just want to compare myself to other predictive models in the field with datasets that is commonly used. And the problem is that I can not find these established baselines in publications.

Comment: If so, then they must not exist. Self-benchmarking of model performance is the way to proceed.